# spyder def command error: not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, function, anaconda, spyder

I'm using Anaconda Invidual Edition 3.7 versio (64-bit) on Windows.
I'm new on Python and writing some basic codes such as pop, insert, append etc, achieved them smoothly.
however, when i try to perform following code, system displays: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

```
def kare(x):
    x**2
```

then i tried to perform it in Jupyter, it performed. I tried it in Anaconda Prompt, system displays "'def' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." error.

I googled it, removing and reinstalling Anaconda was mostly adviced solution, i did them.
I uninstall anaconda, clean files under users and AppData as it is adviced. then install again anaconda and perform same code again. I'm still facing with same error.

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: I'm writing codes on Spyder.

Comment: You can't evaluate code line by line in Spyder. Instead you need to either select the whole block you want to run and press `F9`; or use [cells](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/editor.html#defining-code-cells).

Comment: Yes, now it is working. Thank you